# Scrapy: crawl multiple spiders sharing same items, pipeline, and settings but with separate outputs

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to run multiple spiders using a Python script based on the code provided in the official documentation. My scrapy project contains **multiple spider (*Spider1, Spider2,* etc.)** which crawl different websites and save the content of each website in a different JSON file (*output1.json, output2.json,* etc.).

The items collected on the different websites share the same structure, therefore the spiders use the **same item, pipeline, and setting classes**. The output is generated by a custom JSON class in the pipeline.

When I run the spiders separately they work as expected, but when I use the script below to run the spiders from with scrapy API the items get mixed in the pipeline. ***Output1.json* should only contain items crawled by *Spider1*, but it also contains the items of *Spider2***. How can I crawl multiple spiders with scrapy API using same items, pipeline, and settings but generating separate outputs?

Here is the code I used to run multiple spiders:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from web_crawler.spiders.spider1 import Spider1
from web_crawler.spiders.spider2 import Spider2

settings = get_project_settings()
process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
process.crawl(Spider1)
process.crawl(Spider2)
process.start()
```

Example output1.json:

```
{
"Name": "Thomas"
"source": "Spider1"
}
{
"Name": "Paul"
"source": "Spider2"
}
{
"Name": "Nina"
"source": "Spider1"

}
```

Example output2.json:

```
{
"Name": "Sergio"
"source": "Spider1"
}
{
"Name": "David"
"source": "Spider1"
}
{
"Name": "James"
"source": "Spider2"
}
```

Normally, all the names crawled by spider1 ("source": "Spider1") should be in output1.json, and all the names crawled by spider2 ("source": "Spider2") should be in output2.json

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you are seeing and what you would prefer to see?  I want to help you make this question clearer and more accessible.

Comment: I edited my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acording to [docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process) to run spiders sequentially on the same process, you must chain [deferreds](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/16.5.0/core/howto/defer.html).

Try this:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from web_crawler.spiders.spider1 import Spider1
from web_crawler.spiders.spider2 import Spider2

settings = get_project_settings()
runner = CrawlerRunner(settings)

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def crawl():
    yield runner.crawl(Spider1)
    yield runner.crawl(Spider2)
    reactor.stop()

crawl()
reactor.run()
```

Comment: Thanks. Doing so raise an error:

twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable

Comment: how about all spiders? do you know how can we run all spiders? instead mentioned them one by one ?

Answer (score 4):

The first problem was that spiders were running in the same process. Running the spiders sequentially by chaining the deferreds solved this problem:

```
#scrapy
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging

#spiders
from web_crawler.spiders.spider1 import Spider1
from web_crawler.spiders.spider2 import Spider2

configure_logging()
settings = get_project_settings()
runner = CrawlerRunner(settings)

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def crawl():
    yield runner.crawl(Spider1)
    yield runner.crawl(Spider2)
    reactor.stop()

crawl()
reactor.run()
```

I also had a second mistake in my pipeline: I didn't clear my list of results when close_spider. Therefore, spider2 was adding items to a list that already contained the items of spider1.

```
class ExportJSON(object):

    results = []

    def process_item(self, item, spider):

        self.results.append(dict(item))
        return item

    def close_spider(self, spider):

        file = open(file_name, 'w')
        line = json.dumps(self.results)
        file.write(line)
        file.close()

        self.results.clear()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Better solution is (if you have multiple spiders) it dynamically get spiders and run them.

```
from scrapy import spiderloader
from scrapy.utils import project
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks


@inlineCallbacks
def crawl():
    settings = project.get_project_settings()
    spider_loader = spiderloader.SpiderLoader.from_settings(settings)
    spiders = spider_loader.list()
    classes = [spider_loader.load(name) for name in spiders]
    for my_spider in classes:
        yield runner.crawl(my_spider)
    reactor.stop()

crawl()
reactor.run()
```